# Subset being an Abelian group.

Tags: group-theory

There is a theorem that states:

Let $P(X)$ be the set of subsets of $X$ and let $$\Delta $$ be the *symmetric* difference defined by $$A\Delta B = (A \cup B)\text{$\backslash $(A $\cap $ B)}.$$ Then P(X) is an Abelian group and with each element being its own inverse.

Would someone be nice to simplify this theorem?

Comment: What do you mean by simplifying it? The proof is quite straightforward.

Comment: What is X? Is it a set of real number, integers...?

Comment: $X$ can be any set.

Comment: @user sounds like it's just any set.

Comment: @user $X$ can be any set. It's irrelevant to the proof.

Comment: What is the idea of symmetric difference? The definition has certainly been provided but a simple illustration would help a lot.

Comment: It can also be described as "those elements in precisely one of the sets".

Comment: The symmetric difference of two sets $A,B$ is the set of all elements that are either in $A$ or $B$, but not both. The symmetric difference is like the union but it kills the intersection.

Comment: So suppose, for instance, there are 2 circles overlapping with each other, circle A and circle B. We are interested in all elements from both circle outside of the intersection of the 2 circles.

Comment: Try to write it down for some small examples, like the set $\{1,2,3\}$ and its $8$ subsets. I think you need to get past working with Venn diagrams if you want to really understand this definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "hard" part of this theorem is proving that $\Delta$ is associative. The empty set is easily seen to be an identity element:

$A \Delta \emptyset = (A \cup\emptyset)\setminus(A \cap\emptyset) = A\setminus\emptyset = A$.

and:

$A \Delta A = (A \cup A) \setminus (A \cap A) = A\setminus A = \emptyset$,

for any $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$.